# Css selector equivalent to '//div[contains(@class, 'a b') and not (contains(@style, 'c'))]'

Tags: xpath, selenium, css-selectors

The xpath is `//div[contains(@class, 'a b') and not (contains(@style, 'c'))]`

What would the equivalent CSS selector be? Easy to get first bit `div[class*='a b']`, but how to negate and combine them?

Comment: As @BoltClock implies in his comment to @BenjaminGruenbaum's answer, your `contains(@class, 'a b')` is probably wrong, because it would match `class='da bd'`.  The correct XPath for this is `contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' a b ')`.

Comment: Makes sense. So would `div[class*='a b']` match `class='da bd'` as well? Then what's the equivalent css selector to `contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' a b ')`?

Comment: @user1177636: Yes. The equivalent to that is `.a.b`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You negate using the `:not()` selector and another attribute selector for the `style` attribute. To combine them, just attach the `:not()` to the end of what you already have.

The equivalent CSS selector would be

```
div[class*='a b']:not([style*='c'])
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to select `div` elements with both classes `a` and `b` you can use `div.a.b` .

If you want it not to contain a style attribute with value `c` you can use:

```
div.a.b:not([style*=c])
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. Would `div.a.b:not([style*=c])` and `div[class*='a b']:not([style*=c])` equivalent? Does the order of class names matter in some odd cases?

Comment: Such cases are not odd at all :)

Comment: @user1177636: No, they are not equivalent. `div.a.b` only matches the classes `a` and `b`, whereas `div[class*='a b']` matches a set of two classes, the first of which ends in `a` and the second starts with `b`. This means while `a b` will match, something like `ba bb` will also match. If you really want a strict equivalent of `contains(@class, 'a b')` as opposed to just matching `.a.b`, use the attribute selector. The order of class names within the `class` attribute does not matter, but if you use an attribute selector then it may mess things up a little.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: +1, thank you. BoltClock's answer matches the xpath what I asked in question title, but yes, you were right, `div.a.b` is probably what I want, as `div[class*='a b']` will also match `da bd`.